# SelectIndexChanged not passing parameter to webpart connection

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, web-parts, sharepoint-designer, webpart-connection

In newform.aspx, I have webpart connection. I pass employee-name to the webpart and this webpart renders employee detals. Employee-name field is textbox.

Everything was working fine until I changed the employee-name to be lookup field and when page rendered it became a dropdown. Due to this the connected-webpart always shows the first record in the dropdown during on-load of the page and doesn't refresh when dropdown index is changed.

The entire newform.aspx is customized using sharepoint designer.

I am guessing, I need to write javascript(jquery/json) code and put in newform.aspx using sharepoint designer?

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "I made the employee-name to be dropdown"? Are you using a lookup or a choice field? What was it initially, an empty field?

Comment: @Christophe: Earlier it was a textbox, then I changed it to be lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Part connections are established when the page loads. A change in your employee selection doesn't reload the page so it won't update the connection.

JavaScript/jQuery would certainly be a good choice for this client side behavior. I'd suggest that you check out SPServices on Codeplex, and in particular for your case [SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I went through that link but I am not getting how can I make the employee value to get passed to the connected webpart. Does it happen automatically?

Comment: @Anirudh as I said in my reply, Web Part connections won't work in your case. The solution I pointed to is a replacement for the second Web Part, it will use Web services to pull the employee info and display it on the page.

Comment: The second webpart I have is kind of grid with 1 to n rows and I am thinking how to display it. Not sure how to proceed here.